# Is this model overfitting, underfitting or good fit?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to deep learning and lately have been trying to learn things.
I trained DenseNet-121 and this is the output I recieved

```
Epoch 15/500
12/12 [==============================] - 25s 2s/step - loss: 0.0863 - accuracy: 0.9703 - auc: 0.9951 - val_loss: 0.1536 - val_accuracy: 0.9514 - val_auc: 0.9881
Epoch 16/500
12/12 [==============================] - 27s 2s/step - loss: 0.0936 - accuracy: 0.9649 - auc: 0.9939 - val_loss: 0.1640 - val_accuracy: 0.9453 - val_auc: 0.9850
```

See accuracy and loss graphs here:
[Accuracy and Loss Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7AaA.png)

Is this a good fit? If not then how can I improve on this? Please help me. Thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

You can't answer if it is "a good fit" without understanding the data. You need to be the judge **based on the problem at hand** whether "making a mistake 5% of the time" is a big issue. Imagine that the task is to generate winning lottery ticket. 95% correct would be ASTONISHING. Now imagine that this is a system that creates a cure or a toxin, would you risk taking a drug that can kill you with 5% chance?

When it comes to under/overfit in some sense you observe both. Your model is slightly overfit, because there is a gap between train and validation. At the same time your training is at 97% percent, meaning that it did not fit the training data either.

Comment: "Your model is slightly overfit, because there is a gap between train and validation." This is not a great interpretation.  A large gap in these two accuracies is usually good evidence of overfitting.  However, a lack of a gap is *not* good evidence for not-overfitting.  For example, the training dataset is frequently simply not very representative of data "in-the-wild", and so your training-validation split isn't super meaningful for whether your model will apply to anything that isn't in your original complete set.  "Your model is *at least* slightly overfit" is perhaps more accurate.

Comment: Being not very representative of the data "in the wild" is not a valid term for classical machine learning. Overfitting and underfitting come from a strict literature. I highly recommend taking a look at Statistical Leraning Theory by Vapnik, or any other classic ML book. Being a good fit in statistical sense **does not** mean that your model can just solve everything. In fact you can easily prove that such models do not (and never will) exist. One can of course ask a question of form "is this model fulful my business goal?", but there is no answer to the question on this level of abstraction

Comment: From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting), overfitting is: "the production of an analysis that corresponds too closely or exactly to a particular set of data, and may therefore fail to fit additional data or predict future observations reliably."  It is possible that some authors specifically only focus on the case where good test data is actually available to the researcher.

Comment: To reply to your edit, you *can* reasonably, in general, in statistics, define a population which you are studying and for which your model is supposed to apply.  Usually, defining your population as the particular data that you currently have at hand is not super useful.  So being a good fit in a statistical sense *does* mean that your model can solve problems that extend beyond the boundaries of your sample.  Bootstrapping a test dataset out of your sample does not solve any problems related to how representative your sample is of the population.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what can I try to avoid the overfitting?

Comment: @George [the tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit) specifically recommend first using "more complete" training data, then regularization.  One primitive form of regularization is to simply place bounds on the number of training epochs so that the accuracy on your test and training splits are not very different.  How to get "more complete" training data is context-specific, and, frankly, the difficult/expensive/time-consuming part of building a model.

Comment: @George That question is unanswerable, it is not a programming problem but a research one, you won't get an answer here or anywhere.

Comment: Thanks everyone! :)